# Can resistance training change your skeleton shape?

Tags: hormones, skeleton, shape

I have noticed many weight trainers, including myself, have quite broad shoulders.  Is this an illusion due to added muscle, or is this truly a change in skeletal shape?

I do not have a 'control' to this 'experiment' as I lifted during puberty and thus could have changed body shape due to hormones etc.  I was however quite narrow and skinny when I started.

Additionally, could certain exercises that 'pull' on your joints (like wide grip pullups/pushups) accelerate or increase this effect?

Comment: @Ekaen you should put these types of comments in answers rather than comments.

Comment: Please do not answer in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Strength training certainly can make bones denser and also strengthen the ligaments, although the actual length of a bone is not changed.